# Get Error SessionHandler::read() When installing Magento 2 with Nginx

Tags: magento2, session, nginx

I downloaded magento 2.2.5 and try installing with nginx server, but I got blank page in the installation and then I saw the this error in the report file  :

```
{"0":"Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(\/usr\/share\/nginx\/html\/magento2\/var\/session\/sess_9207bsuqtdoet3h96dmv8vpc41, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in \/usr\/share\/nginx\/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler\/Native.php
```

please somebody help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look like folder `session` on the folder `/magento2/var/` is missing, just create if you does not found it and add permission 755 to that folder, please just read again carefully on your error messages

hope this help

Comment: sorry,  but I'm still newbie on the magento2, I will try your suggestion

Comment: okay, nice to help you. please accept this answer :)